# Authenticate in Django test client with headers

Tags: python, django

I've overridden the `ModelBackend` in my django app. My overridden model backend requires that headers be present in the request to log in the user.

```
HEADER = 'testing'
class TestingModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        testing_header_value = None
        if request is not None and request.META is not None:
            testing_header_value = request.META.get(HEADER, None)

        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username, testing_header_value)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            User().set_password(password)
        else:
            # now validate password and whether the user is active
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

This works perfectly in non test scenarios. However, when I test I'm running into a problem of passing headers with the test client.

The Django test client has a [login](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L586) method but it doesn't pass the `request` [when authenticating](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L594) which means that my model backend can't function correctly - I can't pass the header I need to. Note that one of the parameters in the `authenticate` function is the current request.

I see that I can use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) but that seems a little hack-y. What is the correct way to do this? I suspect subclassing the default test client and overriding the `login` method might be best but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `force_login()` is the best thing to use in your case.